# Google Analytics: Active users on site history

Tags: google-adsense

Google Analytics have nice feature "Real-time > Active users on site (Right now)".

I need to know when and how many people were active on site in history.

GA have "Sessions" statistics, but is not the same. With session statistics i can know how many peoples by in my page per hours.

Comment: I Guess there's no Facility for that.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option to view number of unique users, total users visiting your site in a selected period.

**In The Audience Overview -> Select Users From Dropdown**

[image]